# how to deal with delete buttons in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to know what is the best way to handle delete or edit buttons?

So let's say from a comment box, should I use post or get method for this and then make some validations in the page that is suppose to delete the comment?

As a specific example, I'm gonna point out facebook's comment box, it has a little button for deleting comments, but it doesn't display the `url` in the bottom of the browser, so I guess this uses post method with some jQuery in it. I'm I right? if not what should I use for this type of buttons?

Comment: read the [faq], what have you tried, what worked, what didn't? Post some of your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what Facebook uses, but yes, you should use `POST`. You might want to use something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <p><code>POST</code> should be used for actions which change data.</p>
    <form action="comments/1/delete" method="post" class="delete-form">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```
$(".delete-form").submit(function() {
    var me=$(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: me.attr('action'),
        success: function() {
            me.parent().remove();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Oops! An error occurred while deleting your comment.");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you don't like that the delete button is on a separate line, just style it a bit with CSS:

```
.comment > p,
.comment > .delete-form {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right.
To solve that kind of issues you can either do a classical form which will reload a page after the click or rely on AJAX.
AJAX is an asynchronous way to communicate with a server. In your case, when someone clicks on the button you want it to transmit a request to the server to perform the deletion or edition without reloading the page.
Check out the JQuery get and post functions for a quick start on the topic:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**In the very case of a delete button, you will do a post since it is going to change something on the server side**.